# Purpose of maxZoom property in Google Maps MapType interface?

Tags: javascript

The Google maps API Guide detailing the MapTypes interface states the following with regard to "required" properties:

> maxZoom (required) specifies the maximum zoom level at which to
>   display tiles of this map type.

However, in the example given by Google at:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base

The maxZoom property is NOT even included.

If the code is modified to include the maxZoom property (as shown below), the property has no effect -- should it? Some clarification would be nice ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Overlay map types</title>
   <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
      }
   </style>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
   <script>
      /** @constructor */
      function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
         this.tileSize = tileSize;
         this.maxZoom = 12;   // <--- THIS HAS NO EFFECT ??
      }

      CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function (coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
         var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
         div.innerHTML = coord.toString() +  '<br>zoom: ' + zoom.toString();
         div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
         div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
         div.style.fontSize = '10';
         div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
         div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
         div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
         return div;
      };

      var map;
      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);

      function initialize() {
         var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: chicago
         };
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                           mapOptions);

         // Insert this overlay map type as the first overlay map type at
         // position 0. Note that all overlay map types appear on top of
         // their parent base map.
         map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt( 0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this buried in Google maps documentation in the section entitled "MapType object specification"...

> maxZoom  Type:  number
>
> The maximum zoom level for the map when displaying this MapType.
>   Required for base MapTypes, ignored for overlay MapTypes.

So, a maxZoom property is NOT required for **overlay MapTypes**; which corresponds to the behavior in my original code example.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed `mapType` object's property ( `maxZoom`, `minZoom`, etc... ), the changed effect will take a place ONLY AFTER the map's type will be changed to that `mapType`.

For example , if current `mapType` is `TERRAIN`, and you changed `TERRAIN's` `maxZoom, maxZoom` will work only after changing `mapType` to another type (e.g. `ROADMAP,HYBRID,etc..)` and back to `TERRAIN`.

Instead of setting mapType's maxZoom option,use core map's maxZoom option. Add listener for `"maptypeid_changed"` event, and when event occurs, change `maxZoom` option of map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function(event){
if( map.getMapTypeId() === google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN ){
    map.setOptions({maxZoom:/*For example*/5});
}else 
if( map.getMapTypeId() === google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP ){
    map.setOptions({maxZoom:/*For example*/8});
}//Etc...
else{
    map.setOptions({maxZoom:/*For example*/21});
}
});
```

Comment: I have edited my original question and supplied an example to clarify.